# Calendar HOUR_OF_DAY y MINUTE

Tags: android

tengo este problema:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Log.i("RESULTADO", String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)));
    Log.i("RESULTADO", String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
```

Esto da en el logcat:

```
I/RESULTADO: 10
I/RESULTADO: 40
```

Y son 19:25. El mismo código con un IDE que no sea Android Studio da el resultado correcto. Sabéis por qué falla?

Comment: Revisa la zona horaria del dispositivo. También puedes intentar imprimiendo el resultado de `c.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si son 19:25 deberia tener como resultado 19 y 25 por ser un valor de 24 horas.

Si en otra IDE obtienes valor correcto, me parece que el problema es la zona horaria que se esta tomando por default. Te sugiero definas [la zona horaria.](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html)

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone
                .getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
Log.i("RESULTADO", String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)));
Log.i("RESULTADO", String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
```